# what's different between '(foo bar)' and 'foo bar' in stylus?

Tags: stylus

`func()
   foo bar`

and

`func()
   (foo bar)`

`foo in func()` all return `true`, `bars in func()` all return `false`.

As I know, the `(foo bar)` called `tuple`. What's name about `foo bar`? what's different?

Answer (score 1):

`foo bar` is syntax sugar for `foo: bar`.  In other words, a css rule called `foo` is being assigned the value `bar`.  For example, `color red` and `color: red` are the same.  You can also use this syntax to invoke a function.  For example, if you have a function `foo`, all three of the following are equivalent:

```
foo: bar
foo bar
foo(bar)
```

`(foo bar)` is a Stylus list.

Using the colon-less syntax is not recommended.  It's ambiguous to the Stylus compiler, so it is likely to cause errors in your code.  Colons will be required in the next major version of Stylus.

```
// Never omit colons
color red
// Do this instead
color: red
```